# javascript php editor

Tags: php, javascript, editor, syntax-highlighting

Is there and editor for PHP (or for any other syntax-highlight - able) language, written in javascript and available to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for.

http://ecoder.quintalinda.com/

Answer (score 2):

There's also [TIDE, a Tiny IDE for Javascript](http://www.tide4javascript.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Bespin is also available for downloading.
https://bespin.mozillalabs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want, Mozilla [bespin](https://bespin.mozillalabs.com/) is a good online editor also available to install on your own server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the eclipse editor and install a javascript plugin for it.